# Tower Migration: cpu_fan error

Tags: bios, motherboard, fan

I am moving my hardware to a new tower. Machine is not booting up because of the cpu fan error.

I can see all the fans are physically on on the machine.

I can see on the motherboard that the fans are not moving. This means the hardware of the tower is not communicating with the mobo/Asus software. Thing is I have the tower fan device connected to (b)cpu_opt right now as per the manual. I had the tower fan device plugged into (a)cpu_fan. I moved cable back to (a)cpu_fan. No dice gives a2 error on my mobo.

I believe all hardware components are set up correctly.

Error says press F1 to enter bios so I do. Fans are not spinning on the bios screen. They usually do. So maybe I have to turn something on...

There is a QFan Control so I press it. Next screen only shows options to change speeds of fans. Useless for this scenario.

So it has to be the cable on the tower fan device. Not making sense.

I see CE error on my mobo

I tried another connection on mobo (d)cha_fan2 no dice. I don’t think the asus bios software likes this cable connected.

Thoughts?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by 'Tower Fan Device'. The CPU Heat-sink fan should plug into the motherboard leads for the CPU_FAN. The error you are getting usually indicates that there is no fan present or it has failed. You have a CPU heatsink with a fan, right? Also, what is the RAID-Card looking IC in your bottom pic?

Comment: Also, note that some of the things Case/Fan manufacturers do don't always fit in nicely with the rest of the device stack. I have a Mobo with LED highlights, and fans with controllable LEDs, but to make it all work, you need special controller boxes for the case fans, and specialized software to read the sensors. I can't use the motherboard's fancy thermal configuration for Fans because they are not directly powered by the mobo, and most software (speccy, speedfan, lm-sensors) doesn't see their RPMs at all, and certianly can't control it from in front of that proprietary controller.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! i had to remove the cpu fan cables from the fan chassis on the side of the tower to the cpu fans on the mobo.

Comment: yep. that should be the only one you NEED to wire to the motherboard. I will say that if you can connect the fans directly to your mobo (there isn't a feature that you want that will stop working if you do), you will get a better experience overall, because the motherboard can better scale the fans, and commodity software can read the feedback. Or if you're like me and want your pretty lights, or external dial for manual speed control, you can just accept that your system has come clumsy integration, and live with it.